# Is there a single word for 'internet dissociation'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I responded today on a Stack Exchange site and later realised that my words had been of a slightly different character than if I had, say, left a post-it note on a colleague's desk whom I knew by face-to-face conversation.

This is not because of anonymity as I choose not to be anonymous on the internet and my personal details are freely available to anyone who can be bothered to look.

I was not being deliberately discourteous or disrespectful, nor was I being consciously confrontational or abrupt. But my written response was just lacking in humanity, merely because that person's presence is limited to being transitory (yes, I know it is archived - I mean what is visible) text on a screen.

I have already exhausted my own - related - vocabulary in the preceding paragraph, so what else might fit in the following sentence ?

Because it was an internet communication, my attitude was somewhat _________.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d use ***[impersonal:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impersonal)***

> without human warmth; not friendly and without features that make people feel interested or involved. (Cambridge Dictionary)

- Because it was over the internet my attitude was somewhat impersonal.

or

***[Aseptic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aseptic)*** :

> lacking vitality, emotion, or warmth. (M-W)